# AppSync ReactNative Cognito Promise Rejection

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I have a exception thrown by react native when the app is started and also logged in.

my config is 
"authenticationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
"apiKey": null

cognito is working with appsync, but i don´t know how to fix the alert message.

Any suggestions are welcomed thanks.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with AWS appsync, so I don't know what might be the problem. I can just suggest you one thing,add promise resolver function. That way you can see what it's returning, and it will prevent showing any alert. Something like-

`jwtToken: async () => (await Auth.currentSession()
        .then(data => {
          console.log("data",data);
          return data
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("error",error);
          return err
        })).getIdToken().getJwtToken()`